# Undefined subroutine &Util::disconnect called at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_esx3-0.5.pl line 555

Tags: perl, nagios, esxi

I want to monitor an `esxi` server with the Nagios plugin `check_esxi`. I am getting this error when executing it:

> Undefined subroutine &Util::disconnect called at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_esx3-0.5.pl line 555

I followed [these installation instructions](http://www.artiflo.net/2009/02/monitor-esx35i-avec-nagios3-centreon2/). The Perl libraries and its modules are installed:

```
Nagios::Plugin via CPAN 
perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Bundle::CPAN
cpan> reload CPAN
cpan> install Nagios::Plugin
cpan> install Crypt::SSLeay
cpan> install Compress::Zlib
```

Despite that, the error (which seems to point to a missing library) still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`Util::disconnect()` is defined in `VMware::VIRuntime`, which can be found in `VILib.pm`, which is part of the VMware vSphere SDK for Perl API.  You have to install VMware vSphere SDK for Perl API in order to run check_esx3.pl.

Installation instructions can be found here: https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/How+to+Install+VMware+vSphere+SDK+for+Perl+5.1

More information *(for instance: links to the source)* can be found here:  https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/viperl-1-200706-releasenotes.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct module name where Util::disconnect() is defined is /usr/local/share/perl5/VMware/VICommon.pm

VMware apparently discontinued its support for the VIPER (VMware Infrastructure Perl) SDK.

I ended up locating old 32-bit installation package and placed / modified files manually.